# Why is LWJGL drawing my images weirdly?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Hi guys i am trying to draw a 100 by 100 image to my screen. However when i draw it, openGL draws it half the size of my square with a kind of border round the right and bottom edges.

This is my code:

```
package biz.boulter.lwjglgame;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Game
{   
public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;

private static Texture t;

private static void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    t.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(100, 100); // top-left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(200, 100); // top-right
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(200, 200); // bottom-right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(100, 200); // bottom-left
    glEnd();

}

private static Texture loadTexture(String path) throws Exception{
    return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", Game.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {

        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1000, 1000 / 16*9));
        Display.create();

        t = loadTexture("/assets/guy.png");

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 1000, 1000/16*9, 0, 1, -1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            render();
            Display.sync(60);
            Display.update();
        }   
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
}
```

Why is it doing this. Also i am using slick-util.jar for the texture loading.

ScreenShot:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/13zyflk.jpg

Comment: can anybody answer this??

Comment: It looks like the texture loading library you use might be rounding up the texture size to the next power of 2. So your 100x100 image is loaded as a 128x128 texture.

Comment: what happens if i need an image that isn't a power of two

Comment: I made a tutorial on this a while ago that you can check out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cN3hJ6LphM